# R Selenium - Difficulty Extracting Data from Complex Table

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to webscrape some soccer data. I'm able to loop through all of the necessary web pages, but I'm having trouble getting the data that I need from each page. I think the tables that hold the table are some form of Java, which makes it difficult.

I'm trying to get the goal times for each team from the following website:
http://www.scoreboard.com/uk/match/arsenal-west-brom-2014-2015/AyTNt38e/#match-summary|match-statistics;0|lineups;1

but I can't seem to distinguish between goals/cards/other events that are present. Can anyone help me, or is this simply a lost cause on this website?

My code to get the time of the first event (goal/cards/other) is :

```
library("RSelenium")
startServer()
mybrowser <- remoteDriver()
mybrowser$open()
mybrowser$navigate("http://www.scoreboard.com/uk/match/arsenal-west-brom-2014-2015/AyTNt38e/#match-summary|match-statistics;0|lineups;1")

x<-mybrowser$findElements(using = 'css selector', ".time-box")
x[[1]]$getElementText()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pick a specific parent element that holds only and all the elements that you want. In this case, `"#summary-content div.time-box"` works as the CSS selector.

If you want the event type, e.g. goal vs card vs ..., then you want to use the CSS selector `"#summary-content div.icon-box"` and then look at the other class on the `DIV` element. `soccer-ball` for a goal, `y-card` for a yellow card, and so on. For example,

```
<div class="icon-box soccer-ball">
```

That should be enough to get you started. You should be able to get the rest of them yourself.